# Flexbox wrap issue - Aligning two scrollable divs next to each other in a container of height 100vh

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the following flex box layout to:

1. Have individual scrolling for the Sidebar and the Content area when the content in them overflows
2. Content area to appear next to the sidebar
3. Height of the main container to remain 100vh and neither the sidebar or the content area should exceed this.
4. The alert is for alerting users about issues. It should be on top and should occupy 100% of the width.
5. The user can choose to use the sidebar. If the sidebar is not used, content occupies 100% width. The alert will also only appear when something is wrong. If not then alert will not be shown

I am not sure why the `content` area appears below the `sidebar` and the `sidebar` and the `content` areas don't activate scrolling even after they overflow. You can see that the height of the `sidebar` exceeds the height of the `main` container (the background color of the `main` area is cyan).

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background: cyan;
}
.main .alert {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  order: -2;
}
.main .content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.main .sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="alert">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae explicabo, eum voluptas distinctio quidem, voluptate repudiandae ad aliquam praesentium fuga tempora magni natus necessitatibus consectetur minima maxime, placeat consequatur optio.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos error animi consequatur doloribus maiores in delectus esse illo fugit quod distinctio, voluptatem omnis earum voluptate corporis facere ea enim laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo maxime sit ab blanditiis eum, consequatur aspernatur odio nobis fuga, sed ratione dignissimos dolores nulla ea eaque. Officia, dolore harum nemo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque iste impedit, tenetur libero earum, rerum sit, voluptates, similique perferendis magnam voluptatem optio saepe perspiciatis. Doloribus excepturi iure, hic quasi architecto.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, at odit accusantium, maiores doloremque placeat doloribus repellat optio magnam suscipit eius libero tempore, iure, voluptatum facere ut saepe nam. Debitis.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga facere enim quas vero quisquam possimus eius cum nisi adipisci, non ipsam architecto explicabo. Quis dolor cum earum quas consequuntur, maiores!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga quis provident quo, vel nesciunt deserunt vitae quae nulla, mollitia, assumenda et tenetur illum exercitationem numquam! Distinctio sapiente maxime, ullam expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia aliquid numquam, officiis accusamus dolor commodi quae soluta reprehenderit iusto laboriosam nostrum, natus vel impedit, enim inventore, consectetur harum deleniti consequuntur!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `max-width = 65%` for `.main .content` works fine for me

Comment: but what happens if someone chooses not to have a sidebar. the content should take the entire width then plus it doesn't activate scrolling on overflow. the max container should have a height of 100vh

Comment: What do you mean? You will have some "button" which will toggle (show/hide) your sidebar? If yes, then you can change attribut to `max-width: 100%` with `onclick` action.

Comment: the reason i chose to use flexbox is because if a user chooses not the use a sidebar, the content area will occupy 100% of the width. also the above solution does not handle the scrolling issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method #1: `flex-direction:column` and nested flex container

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: cyan;
}
.main .alert {
  flex: 1 1 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
.inner-flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.inner-flex-container .content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.inner-flex-container .sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="alert">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="inner-flex-container">
    <div class="content">
      Content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam
      magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus
      voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos
      obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse,
      minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae explicabo, eum voluptas distinctio quidem, voluptate repudiandae ad aliquam praesentium fuga tempora magni natus necessitatibus consectetur minima maxime, placeat consequatur optio.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos error animi consequatur doloribus maiores in delectus esse illo fugit quod distinctio, voluptatem omnis earum voluptate corporis facere ea enim laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Quo maxime sit ab blanditiis eum, consequatur aspernatur odio nobis fuga, sed ratione dignissimos dolores nulla ea eaque. Officia, dolore harum nemo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque iste impedit,
      tenetur libero earum, rerum sit, voluptates, similique perferendis magnam voluptatem optio saepe perspiciatis. Doloribus excepturi iure, hic quasi architecto. Eaque iste impedit, tenetur libero earum, rerum sit, voluptates, similique perferendis
      magnam voluptatem optio saepe perspiciatis. Doloribus excepturi iure, hic quasi architecto. Eaque iste impedit, tenetur libero earum, rerum sit, voluptates, similique perferendis magnam voluptatem optio saepe perspiciatis. Doloribus excepturi iure,
      hic quasi architecto. Eaque iste impedit, tenetur libero earum, rerum sit, voluptates, similique perferendis magnam voluptatem optio saepe perspiciatis. Doloribus excepturi iure, hic quasi architecto. Eaque iste impedit, tenetur libero earum, rerum
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      Sidebar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, at odit accusantium, maiores doloremque placeat doloribus repellat optio magnam suscipit eius libero tempore, iure, voluptatum facere ut saepe nam. Debitis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga facere enim quas vero quisquam possimus eius cum nisi adipisci, non ipsam architecto explicabo. Quis dolor cum earum quas consequuntur, maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt
      corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi
      ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem
      dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati
      optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima
      assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Fuga quis provident quo, vel nesciunt deserunt vitae quae nulla, mollitia, assumenda et tenetur illum exercitationem numquam! Distinctio sapiente maxime, ullam expedita. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia aliquid numquam,
      officiis accusamus dolor commodi quae soluta reprehenderit iusto laboriosam nostrum, natus vel impedit, enim inventore, consectetur harum deleniti consequuntur!
    </div>
  </div><!-- close .inner-flex-container -->
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ej1ab97v/3/)

Notes:

- Added `body { margin: 0; }` to prevent overflow and vertical scrollbar when `.main` has `height: 100vh`.
- Switched `flex-direction` of `.main` to `column` to establish vertical stacking.
- Wrapped second and third flex items (`.content` and `.sidebar`, respectively) in their own flex container, which has `flex-direction` row so items are stacked horizontally below the first flex item (`.alert`).

---

### Method #2: `flex-wrap:wrap` and `calc()`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: cyan;
}
.alert {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}
.content {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  order: 1;
}
.sidebar {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="alert">
    Hello
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni
    quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus
    voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos
    obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse,
    minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae explicabo, eum voluptas distinctio quidem, voluptate repudiandae ad aliquam praesentium fuga tempora magni natus necessitatibus consectetur minima maxime, placeat consequatur optio. Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos error animi consequatur doloribus maiores in delectus esse illo fugit quod distinctio, voluptatem omnis earum voluptate corporis facere ea enim laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Quo maxime sit ab blanditiis eum, consequatur aspernatur odio nobis fuga, sed ratione dignissimos dolores nulla ea eaque. Officia, dolore harum nemo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque iste impedit, tenetur
    libero earum, rerum sit, voluptates, similique perferendis magnam voluptatem optio saepe perspiciatis. Doloribus excepturi iure, hic quasi architecto. Eaque iste impedit, tenetur libero earum, rerum sit, voluptates, similique perferendis magnam voluptatem
    optio saepe perspiciatis. Doloribus excepturi iure, hic quasi architecto.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, at odit accusantium, maiores doloremque placeat doloribus repellat optio magnam suscipit eius libero tempore, iure, voluptatum facere ut saepe nam. Debitis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga facere enim quas vero quisquam possimus eius cum nisi adipisci, non ipsam architecto explicabo. Quis dolor cum earum quas consequuntur, maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt
    corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi
    ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem
    dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio
    pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda
    eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt corrupti, nulla fugiat recusandae quae necessitatibus voluptatem dicta ut numquam libero tenetur consequatur esse, minima assumenda eum debitis amet quia reiciendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius veniam magni quasi ad sunt qui voluptatum repellat officia deleniti eos obcaecati optio pariatur nesciunt non vitae earum a, rem eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga quis provident
    quo, vel nesciunt deserunt vitae quae nulla, mollitia, assumenda et tenetur illum exercitationem numquam! Distinctio sapiente maxime, ullam expedita. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia aliquid numquam, officiis accusamus
    dolor commodi quae soluta reprehenderit iusto laboriosam nostrum, natus vel impedit, enim inventore, consectetur harum deleniti consequuntur!
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ej1ab97v/5/)

Notes:

- No changes to HTML
- `calc` used to subtract height of flex item one from height of flex items two and three, enabling them to wrap underneath in a 100vh container.

Comment: this works. thanks for the reply. i have upvoted your solution but i still don't understand why i have to wrap it in a div? since flex is set to wrap shouldn't the div appear next to each other?

Comment: is it because a block element by default has to occupy 100% width unless until specified?

Comment: @takeradi, you don't have to wrap items in a div creating a nested flex container. That's just one method that I tend to favor. Using your original HTML with `flex-wrap: wrap` is also possible. I posted a second method in my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Edited to add the wrapper

```
.content{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: blue;
    overflow-y: auto; */
    width: calc(100% - 200px); // Or use flex: 1 where you got flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.main .sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    overflow-y: auto;
    order: -1;
}

.wrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i wont be able to use this solution because the alert may or may not be shown depending on the state of the app and since you are calculating height, it wont work in cases where the alert is not shown :(

Comment: You only have to wrap .content and .sidebar inside a div, style that div with display:flex and flex:wrap and remove the max-height from the childs, that would work. I have added the wrapper and final code to it!